# How are exceptions handled in PHP?

Tags: php

Can anybody tell me how are exceptions handled in PHP? I have this code

```
try{
   $this->b->methodthatraisesexception();
}
catch(Exception $ex){
  echo "Hi Hi hi, you tried to deleted a non existing file";
}
```

When i try to run this code instead of seeing the `echo` message, i see some kind of weird `PHP error occured` message. Btw, the above method is contained in `A`'s class which handles exceptions. It is calling to `b`'s method which generates error but doesn't have `try catch`. I see the below given error. Instead of my own `echo` statement. Please let me know if anything is unclear.

**EDIT**

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: unlink(C:/Program Files/wamp/www/\College\uploads\4c4b29de80e39.jpg) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory

Filename: models/settings.php

Line Number: 31
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: i see some kind of weird PHP error occured
And what might that error be?

Comment: Please read my edited post. How do i prevent this error and show my own echo message?

Comment: Please, don't edit the question to the point where the original meaning changes drastically.  Add to post (and of course, correct errors, typos, that kind of thing.)

Comment: That's not a PHP error.. that's a CodeIgniter error. Or like it says, a warning.

Comment: @Cole Regardless, that's a result of the PHP warning for that same condition, i.e. a failure in unlink().  It may be prettied up by CI, but that doesn't change anything significant to this question.  (Well, unless Nitesh wants to prevent the warning from showing up in the browser.  Though, I'd assume using PHP's builtin `error_reporting` and/or `display_errors` would/could be used.)

Comment: What I do for my file handling classes is temporary install my own errorhandler with set_error_handler that handles the E_WARNING. In the error handler function I first restore the original error handler and then throw the error string as an exception. Either that or you can use the silence operator (@) and check for the return code (but I am principally against this operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unlink() doesn't throw exceptions.

> A E_WARNING level error will be
> generated on failure.
>
> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on
> failure.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

As far as throwing exceptions, you just throw 'em.  You don't declare that the class throws them.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Update:

Basically, do this where unlink() is called:

```
if(unlink('somefile'))
{
    // success condition
}
else
{
    // failure condition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You guys may want to checkout a service to track exceptions. Which is called [ErrorApp](http://errorapp.com)

This service will help to track exceptions in PHP projects.